# Dell Inspiron 1501 will not turn on

Tags: troubleshooting, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 1501 purchased December 2007 and no warranty remaining. Today, the laptop will not turn on. I followed these Dell troubleshooting instructions, but still no success:

> [Computer does not turn on, or is stuck on the Dell logo screen](http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/kcs/document?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs&docid=DSN_361764&isLegacy=true)

**Additional information:**

- The AC adapter LED is green (when plugged into the laptop and when not)
- The LEDs on the battery are green (when the button next to them is
  pressed, when plugged into the laptop and when not)
- I removed the memory, hard drive, battery, held down the power button for 20 seconds,
  plugged in the AC adapter, and noticed the power light and fan
  briefly turn on and off. Pressing the power button does nothing.

Any recommendations?

If the motherboard needs to be replaced, a quick Google search shows prices around $200 (from a reputable PC shop). Dell's [motherboard replacement documentation](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/ins1501/en/sm_en/sysboard.htm#wp1000473) looks in-depth and time consuming and a repair I might consider leaving to a certified technician. On the other hand, a new low end Dell laptop starts for about $500, less for a refurbished model.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the motherboard or the screen. Get a new one.  It will save you work and you get a new warranty.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you did, it sounds like the motherboard is probably shot. If you can get another power supply, you can try that, but I would not have much hope.

As you alluded to, a new one, even refurbished, is probably a better way to go, but you have to look at the specifics as to cost for a replacement board, versus the possibly better specs of the newer computer.

Comment: The only reason I mention possible replacement would be if you could get some kind of great deal, like on eBay possibly. In most cases, as in all three answers, usually we would lean toward replacement of the whole computer.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the motherboard. Does not pay to fix, and I say this as someone who usually prefers repair to replace.